# Shape of a new variable must be fully defined, but instead was (?, 128)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a multi layer convolution network using Tensorflow.I had no issues for two layers.For the third layer,when I define the weight,it gives me error **Shape of a new variable must be fully defined, but instead was (?, 128).**
I saw this [SOF link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135436/why-cant-i-access-the-variable-i-create-using-the-variable-name-plus-scope-path) and used **reuse=True**, but the error persists.Any help would be really helpful.

Below is my code:

```
with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
    reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, shape=[batch_size, -1])
    dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights',
                              shape=[dim,128],
                              dtype=tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.005,dtype=tf.float32))
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases',
                             shape=[128],
                             dtype=tf.float32, 
                             initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
```

Here **batch_size is 32** and **pool2 is a tensor of shape=(?, 14, 14, 16)**.

Note:This code works when I execute it inside a function.Why so?

Comment: Please give more code that reproduces the problem

Comment: @george  Did you solve your issue? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of your weights is not fully defined, which isn't allowed for a Tensorflow variable.
`dim` can't be computed before your run a session because it depends on the shape of `pool2`, which is undefined on first dimension.

If the actual shape of `pool2` will be **(batch_size, 14, 14, 16)**, I recommend you to do the following changes to your code (untested):

```
import numpy as np

with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
    dim = np.prod(pool2.get_shape()[1:]).value
    reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, shape=[-1, dim])
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights',
                              shape=[dim, 128],
                              dtype=tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.005,dtype=tf.float32))
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases',
                             shape=[128],
                             dtype=tf.float32, 
                             initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
```

`dim` is now **14*14*16** instead of **?**, thus your weights now have a fully defined shape. Moreover, you will be able to change `batch_size` between runs without having to rebuild your computation graph as `batch_size` isn't used anymore to define tensor shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of error while using tensorflow==1.9.0 Try to upgrade it to tensorflow==1.11.0 It works for me!